# How can I generate a Warning when using certain RTL/VCL or Delphi language elements

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I would like to mark certain elements, functions and classes as deprecated, so that the compiler generates a warning.

My intention is to modernize certain aspects of the source. Especially when focusing on more platform independence.

E.g. By marking the WinAPI and special Windows classes (such as TRegistry) as "deprecated" they could be replaced or at least moved and made platform independent.
As for the language elements, I would especially like to deprecate the `with`, `label` and `goto` keywords.

I already tried to generate a warning for functions and classes by inserting a `{$IF DECLARED(...)}{$MESSAGE WARN...}` into the bottom of the unit file, but this will evidently fail with the core units...

Does somebody know a Tool that does this?

Comment: AFAIK, this  isn't possible. You can use the `deprecated` keyword on your own code where it's declared, but it has no effect on the core units or code constructs like `goto`. Delphi already warns about platform-specific code to a certain extent; XE2 makes things relatively transparent when you change platforms (as much as possible, anyway).

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly why I'm asking if there is a tool that does the job. The ToolsAPI should provide all that is needed to link into the Build and Messaging.

Comment: Look for static code analysis tools, I'm sure there will be one with options for what you require.

Comment: @TobiasR AFAIK the ToolsAPI is a collection of classes and functions for extending and enhancing Delphi's design environment, not the Delphi Compiler. Just to mention that there is a command-line compiler. It may be interesting to have a plug-in system at the compiler level, but it will definitively be not part of the ToolsAPI. Or you may want to use FreePascal, and change the source code to let the compiler matches your exact needs.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I'm not that into the details of the ToolsAPI (yet) but as far as I understand, you can add a AfterCompile Notifier and gain access to the MessagingServices of the IDE.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `with` if not used improperly. Symbols can be made to emit warning, but not reserved words.

Comment: What I do is simply refrain from writing `goto`, `with` etc. I can assure you that I find it incredibly easy to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to warnings, you could go with a simple app that parses all source code and reports the use of these constructs.

With a little investigation, I'm sure you can find some static code analysis tools that will even go a bit further and alert you to certain code-smells. (E.g. incorrect use of try..finally, swallowed exceptions).

Plug the app or the static code analyser in as a step in your build process, and you have the equivalent to compile-time warnings.

Comment: Interesting. Does somebody know if I can define custom Audits in the IDE?

Comment: This seems to be the fastest solution (for now). Of course the RTL is very platform independent (at least I hope - I've yet not fully tested), but I think every developer has once in a while frowned because the RTL has little bug here and there or may not be up to date with current OS developments. This will hopefully change in future but until then I'll keep a couple of workarounds and fixes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can deprecate keywords like `with`, `goto`, etc. If you want to modernize your code, simply look for these words as whole word and if you find them, change your code.

The same is true for identifiers in the Win.* core units. You could modify the RTL and recompile it, or you could download the JEDI API headers from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/files/JEDI%20API%202.3%20and%20JEDI%20WSCL%200.9.3.zip/download?_test=goal) and designate all the routines and types `platform`, or just the units. I would recommend against recompiling the RTL. What you do with, say, units from JEDI, is up to you.

Except for the Win.* units, most of the RTL is actually platform independent, and even `with`and `goto` will work in 64 bit or on the Mac too.

My advice: find a better way to modernize your code. Don't try to deprecate what the RTL offers.

Comment: Actually, this was disturbing me since introduction of hint directives - why `Windows` unit was never marked `platform` while it definitely is platform-specific as long as all symbols introduced in it. I'm aware of older unit aliases mechanism used to cross-platform compiling, but still, this situation is so improper. /rant

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a warning on core language features like `with`, `label` and `goto` no matter how much you hate them.
The fact that these are reserved words should have tipped you off on this.

These features are not in any unit, they are a feature of the Pascal language (and have been since its beginning) and build deep into the compiler.

You can't even redefine them because they are reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

**First, I do NOT advise you go the route you want to go in, for all the reasons others have stated.  BUT, if you feel you must, then here is a method that will do some of what you are asking for.**

You can turn on warnings for `platform` specific code in your project.  As for other things that you consider deprecated but are not actually deprecated by Delphi, I have a solution that will take some work.

Create a unit that redeclares the classes that you want deprecated, like the following:

```
unit PleaseDeprecateThisStuff;

uses
  Registry;

interface

type
  TRegistry = class (Registry.TRegistry)
  end deprecated;

implementation

end;
```

EDIT2: I feel I should explain the source further.  For each class, like the `TRegistry` example, you'll need to include a same-name version of it in this unit and make it identical to the version in another unit.  Make sure you include that unit in the uses clause of this unit (duh) AND prefix the class reference in the type section, like the example of `Registry.TRegistry`.

Include everything you want deprecated and then include this unit at the **end** of the **interface** `uses` clause of EVERY unit you want to "protect".

EDIT: This trick will only help with classes, variables, and constants... not reserved words.

Again, let me state this is a horrible idea.  :p

Comment: I don't think that I'm trying to do something horrible, But thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but its not feasible for larger projects.

Comment: Sorry, that last "horrible" was mostly at my suggestion, since it is a hack at best and requires quite a bit of work to do what you are asking.